# Manipulate JSON from AWS S3 in Python AWS Lambda

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to read to manipulate the key and values (JSON file) from a S3 Bucket.
I can `json.loads()` if I decode as UTF-8 after `get()/read()` (first example) but my `for` is printing char by char:

```
content_object = s3.Object(bucket, s3_key)

file_content = content_object.get()["Body"].read()
#print(file_content) ->  
# b'{"KEY1":"VALUE1 ","KEY2":0,"KEY3":"R"}
# {"KEY4":"VALUE1 ","KEY5":0,"KEY6":"R"} 
# (... multiple lines)

file_content_decoded = file_content.decode("utf-8")

# here I can json.loads, but when I try to run through, it's printing char by char instead line by line:
file_loaded = json.loads(file_content_decoded)

for item in file_loaded:
    print(item)

# item = printing char by char ex: { , " , K , E ... each iteration print char by char
```

If I try to decode when I read, I can't `json.loads` and I don't know why.

```
file_content = content_object.get()["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")

file_loaded = json.loads(file_content)
for item in file_loaded:
    print(item)

# error from lambda when "file_loaded = json.loads(file_content)":
   msg = msg % self.args
  "errorMessage": "not all arguments converted during string formatting",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
```

I want to iteract with each line to access and manipulate that keys and values.
I created a local project to test those executions replacing `content_object.get()["Body"].read()` to `with open("file") as f:` and I have no problems:

```
with open("file_downloaded_from_S3_manually.json") as f:
    for json_object in f:
        
        data = json.loads(json_object)
        for item in data:
            print(item)
            # item = printing keys (correctly): KEY1 , KEY2 ...
```

I figure out that my json is starting with `b'` but after some researches I didn't found any material to load that format. Thks for your help. And if I can write more information to your understand, let a comment, please!

Comment: What is the actual content of the file? If the content really is `{"KEY1":"VALUE1 "...}{"KEY4":...}` then that is not valid JSON.

Comment: I can't copy paste here cause i'm on my work pc and it is blocked, but is something like: 
`{"N":"J ","D":0,"I":"R"}
{"N2":"J","D2":0,"I2":"R"}
{"N3":"J","D3":0,"I3":"R"} `
note: Local, when I read from `with open` works with same json

Comment: Your last snippet iterates through `f` first, presumable through the lines of the file, you need to do something similar on lambda.

Comment: This might be a good use-case for using **Amazon S3 Select**, which can run SQL-like queries on files containing JSON data, where each line contains a separate JSON object. See: [SELECT Command - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, nice aws service, I will consider it. We was considered to use Glue too, but both sounds better than Lambda for this use-case. thanks a lot.

Comment: thks @luk2302, this work well after iterates through lines.